# how to apply onTouchEvent in recyclerview child inside the child?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had made a navigation drawer which is having header footer and list. I wonder *how to apply touch event in specific navigation drawer header image and footer.*

I'm having navigation drawer with Header which contain Image and name of the user then in between list of items  and then footer.

All the xml file(Header, CustomRow and footer) are in `recyclerView`,

> so i want basically functionality to click header image,customrom and
>   footer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `recyclerview` you must have `ViewHolder` as well. Yes? Your problem is fixed.

You can define `clickListeners` within `ViewHolder`

 Taking an example -

```
class AddedProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mCardContainer;

    AddedProductHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.conatiner);
        // Define clickListener here...
        mCardContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do your stuff.. If you need position of item clicked.. user getAdapterPosition()
            }
        });
    }
}
```